# Calendar date/time validation syntax help

Tags: validation

I'm trying to prevent users from submitting calendar entries after 10am for day-of appointments.  So, no restriction for submissions any day other than today, just no updates to current day after 10am.

So, something like =IF(OR([appointment date]>[create date]),([create time]<10:00am))

As illustrated, I'm not great at validation syntax, so any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract hour using below syntax

```
TEXT([FieldName],"h")
```

Now you can add the validation as

```
=INT(TEXT([FieldName],"h")) > 10
```

So the complete formula will be something like

```
=AND([AppointmentDate]=TODAY(), INT(TEXT([AppointmentDate],"h")) > 10)
```